# ExtJS - Combobox with Date Picker

Tags: extjs, combobox, datepicker, extjs4, xtype

How would one configure a combobox component to contain both store-bound items, as well as a calendar picker in the display field (for manual entry)?

Comment: can you provide a screenshot or a mockup of what you are trying to create?

Answer (score 0):

It isn't really clear but what you want exaclty but you can override the [createPicker](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox-method-createPicker) method on the combobox. That way you can put anything in the picker.

e.g. a container with a vbox layout containing a calender picker and a grid/boundlist

I have done something similar once. I have one where I've overridden the picker to contain a tree. You just have to return the component and bind actions. (itemclicks etc)

Comment: My implementation is pretty custom and integrated into the app but sencha has an [implementation](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.ux.TreePicker) too here's [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/Vandeplas/enUnk/1/)